# Log out all users from database for maintenance

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a front-end back-end database in MS Access 2007 that is only used during work hours.

I'd like to be able log-off all users that left the front-end running to do some maintenance.

I'd like to do it without timers as that makes editing weird and it won't really help me now as I have no idea where all the versions are.

Any solutions to this?

Comment: this solution works, but it's really a workaround - i can rename the folder on the server and then create a new folder with the same name and copy the backend only there and edit it. Good enough for what i need really even if it's not the right way

Answer (score 0):

Using a timer in the front-end is the only 'graceful' way in Access, apart from disconnecting the network path as you have effectively done.